# Simple way to save list of items and display them using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I want to load an html page with a text box, "add" and "remove" buttons, and an empty text field below.

If I type "Sally" and click the add button, "Sally" appears in the text field below.
Then I type "Greg" and click the add button, "Greg" appears under Sally.
Then I type "Sally" and click the remove button, and only "Greg" remains in the text box.

I want "Greg" to still be the only item displayed in the text box when I close and re-open the page later.

Is the most efficient way to do this to serialize() the items that are typed in the text box, and then deserialize them in order to display them? Or is there a better/more efficient way to do this.

Edit: This method needs to be offline, using an SQL database/etc. is not an option.

Comment: Can you include what have you done so far

Comment: Essentially I have everything that I have described, but the "add/remove" buttons currently just display text on the text field below - there's no real data saving going on anywhere. I'm still early on in this project and just want to make sure I'm progressing in the right direction. I can include my html/jquery files if that would help

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store this information in [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

After every time a user presses the add or remove button you:

1. Update your JS array (either add the item, remove the
   item if it exists, etc)
2. Visually update your text field where you display the array items.
3. Serialize the array and save it to local storage (which if you click on the link above, you can see how to do)
4. On page load, reload the serialized array from localstorage, unserialize it, save it to a variable on the page, and visually update your text field where you display the array items.

Comment: Thank you alex - I know I just needed to ask so that I could get some keywords to read up on - I think localstorage was what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure - let me know if you run into an issues along the way.